# How does the operating system recognize end of a text file?

Tags: c, operating-system, eof

For example, there is a text file called "Hello.txt"

`Hello World!`

Then how does the operating system (I'm using MS-DOS) recognize the end of this text file? Is some kind of character or symbol hidden after '!' which indicates the end of file?

Comment: MS-DOS uses FAT (file allocation table), which maintains the size (along with other attributes) of each file. This is also the case for any other file type (i.e., not only for text files).

Comment: Also, some MS-DOS (and some Windows) programs support an 'end-of-text' character "Control+Z" (often written as `^Z`), which causes no end of portability issues.  It comes from CP/M originally.  There is a short paragraph here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file.  However that is not the same as the *operating system* recognising it.

Comment: Its also worth pointing out (as @barakmanos hinted) that so far as the operating system (OS) is concerned there is nothing special about a text file.  A file consists of the bytes between start-of-file and end-of-file, what happens between them is up to the application.  Even file extensions are not meaningful to the OS, only to the application.

Comment: The answer depends upon the operating system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use MS-Dos then there are some odds that there is indeed a special character at the end of the string.  MS-Dos was derived from Tim Paterson's QDos who wrote it to be as compatible as possible with the then-dominant CP/M.  An OS for 8-bit machines, it kept track of a file size by only counting the number of disk sectors used by the file.  Which made the file size always a multiple of 128 bytes.

Which required a hack to indicate the real end of a text file, since it could be located in the middle of a sector, it used the Ctrl+Z control character (character code 0x1A).  Which required a language runtime implementation to remove it again and declare end-of-file when it encounters the character.  Ctrl+Z is not quite forgotten, it still works when you type it in a Windows console to terminate input.  Compare to Ctrl+D in a Unix terminal.

Whether it *actually* is present in the file depends on what program created the file.  Which would have to be an MS-Dos program as well to get the Ctrl+Z appended.  It is certainly not required.  Paterson improved on CP/M to remove some of its restrictions, greatly aided by having a lot more address space available (1 MB vs 64 KB), MS-Dos keeps track of the actual number of *bytes* in a file.  So it can always reliable indicate the true end of a file.  Which is probably the most accurate answer to your question.

Ancient history btw, invest your time wisely.